# The integral $\int \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos^4(x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Hey I'm having problem solving this integral :

$$\int \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos^4(x)}dx$$

I think we should use $t=\sin(x)$ but it's not working for me.
and if I use $t=\tan(x/2)$ it gets worse. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: $\sin^3(x)=\sin^2(x) \sin x$ will help.

Comment: yes I found it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $t=\cos x$ then $dt=-\sin x \, dx$ hence
$$\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\cos^4x}dx=-\int\frac{1-t^2}{t^4}dt$$
can you take it from here?

Comment: How did you get away with the $sin^2(x)$ ?

Comment: $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$.

Comment: oh now it's ok great thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The integrand is $$\tan^3x \sec x=\tan^2 x \cdot (\tan x \sec x)=(\sec^2 x-1)\cdot(\tan x \sec x)$$

Comment: by this we make it more simple ?

Comment: and the integral is $(1/3)\sec^3x-\sec x+c$

Comment: @WasFr is it clear now

Comment: Yes man ! nice I liked the trick

Comment: Glad to help out @WasFr

Answer (score 4):

Use $\sin^3(x) = \sin(x)-\cos^2(x)\sin(x)$, makes it trivial.

Comment: nice ! I did not think about this

Comment: As soon as you see an odd power of a sine/cosine you can think of the $c^2+s^2=1$ identity. $c^n = s'(1-s^2)^{n-1\over 2}$, $s^n=-c'(1-c^2)^{n-1\over 2}$

Comment: Yes I agree, and it is good to know .

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int\frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^4 x}\,dx =\int\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^4 x}\Big(\sin x \, dx\Big) = \int\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\cos^4 x} \Big(\sin x \, dx\Big) = \int \frac{1-u^2}{u^4}(-du)
$$
$$
= \int \left(\frac{1}{u^4} - \frac{1}{u^2}\right) \, (-du)
$$